# Is there a config file to set the default network in a file for Metamask extension? I want to be able to set it as the Polygon network when it starts

Tags: metamask, polygon

I'm forking the metamask extension and I want to set the Polygon Network as the main network in my fork of Metamask. Is there a config file I can just edit to add this in before a user sets up their account?